# Возможно ли сделать звонок из приложения без набора номера?

Tags: java, android

Использую такую конструкцию. При нажатии возникает экран набора номера с уже введенным номером. Заменять DIAL на CALL пробовал, эффекта ноль.

Так-то все работает, но мне хотелось бы, что бы выполнялся звонок в один клик, без нажатия кнопки "звонить" на экране набора номера.

```
    public void dial(View v) {
        dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567"));
        startActivity(dialIntent);
    }
```

---

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473436/revoked-permission-android-permission-call-phone

Comment: Что значит что при замене эффекта ноль? Что-то да должно происходить, вы ж код поменяли) в манифесте разрешения есть? Смотрите в логе когда нажимаете кнопку что там происходит

Comment: происходит тоже самое - открывается экран набора номером с тем номером, который я указал для интента. В манифесте конечно, иначе вылет с ошибкой)

Comment: `ACTION_CALL` должен звонить. Возможно производитель вашего телефона что-то "усовершенствовал". https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CALL